# How to create JSON Structure in the following manner

Tags: jquery

I am trying to JSON Structure in the following manner

```
[{
    "emp": {
        "name": "Ram",
        "email": "Ram@gmail.com"
    },
    "location": {
        "name": "John"
    }
}]
```

tried the below , but the structure is not coming , can u please help

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var selection = [];


emp = {}
location = {};

emp["name"] = 'Ram'
emp["email"] = 'Ram@gmail.com'

location["name"] = "UK"

selection.push(emp);
selection.push(location);



});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hjq25xku/2/

Comment: It would be good to include what structure you code does produce _in the question_.

Comment: Try `selection.push({emp, location});`

Comment: In your desired output your `emp` and `location` structures are contained within the same Object, but all you've done here is just add them to the same Array - seems you're missing a layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `emp` and `location` to live within another object and then push only that object into `selection`. So something like:

```
var wrapper = { location: location, emp: emp };
selection.push(wrapper);
```